# Ionic CLI: [ERROR] Gulpfile (or dependent module) not found: .\gulpfile.js

Tags: ionic-framework, gulp, ionic3, ionic-cli

#### Senario

I recently upon running an Ionic 3 app, updated (*well accidentally*) the Ionic CLI version. Now upon running the build from command line, it produces the following error every time and halts the build:

[image]

In the error message it says to disable the gulp integration by running the command `ionic config set gulp.enabled false` which I did. But still getting the same error. I also tried to add the command to the `start` script of `package.json` to no avail (*not needed though since it seems the config is set globally*).

Any help would be appreciated.

#### Ionic CLI version: 3.9.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally figured out what the problem was. Even if Gulp integration has been disabled with the command `ionic config set gulp.enabled false`, as long as Gulp is a **Dev dependency** (*i.e. there is a reference to it in the `package.json` under `devDependencies`*) the Ionic CLI would (well, logically) assume that the Ionic project has a dependency on Gulp, therefore would throw the error (*see original post*).

### Solution

The solution for a case where you don't want Gulp integration, apart from disabling it by running the command `ionic config set gulp.enabled false`, is to also make sure Gulp is NOT under the `devDependencies` in the `package.json` file.

Hope this helps anyone else with a similar issue.

---

**NOTE:** Not sure from which version onwards Ionic requires integration with Cordova and Gulp in the shape of `ionic.config.json` file. Anyway, the above solution will be relevant for a similar case in any of those versions.

Comment: Thanks i had this problem for about 3 days your solution saved me from going on for 4th 5th etc...

Comment: I have no references to gulp in my package.json and still get the error that gulp is not installed.  I have gulp.enabled set to false in my ionic.config.json.

Comment: I resolved my issue by running the following command: ionic config set integrations.gulp.enabled false.  Note the introduction of the integrations object.  The Ionic error message in the CLI tells you to run ionic config set gulp.enabled false, which did not work for version 3.20.0.

Comment: YOOOEE - Your solution (ionic config set integrations.gulp.enabled false) worked for me.

Comment: 2021:  None of the solution above worked for me.